# Having trouble using a file as a command-line argument in the same directory as the python script

Tags: python, python-3.x, command-line-arguments

I'm trying to write a .py script that takes in another file as a command argument, with the cmd-argument file in the same directory as said script.

What I have so far is:

```
import sys
java_file = open(sys.argv[1],"r")
<rest of file>
```

Which works fine if I have a command-line argument like this:

```
python.exe "D:\<user>\<more file directories>\balanced.py" "D:\<user>\<same file directories>\Driver.java"
```

What I'd like to do is have the command-line argument be something like:

```
python.exe "D:\<user>\<more file directories>\balanced.py" Driver.java
```

Running on Windows 10 command prompt using Python 3.7.3.

Comment: you can use [os.getcwd()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/os_getcwd.htm) in your balanced.py

Comment: os.getcwd() will return the directory from which he is running the python executable, not the head of the script file path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on Windows, `sys.argv[0]` should be the full path to your script, so you can use `os.path.split(sys.argv[0])[0]` to get the path, then `os.path.join()` to join it

```
import sys, os
java_file = open(os.path.join(os.path.split(sys.argv[0])[0], sys.argv[1]))
```

Comment: It works, may I ask what is the usage of the second ```[0]``` in ```os.path.split(sys.argv[0])[0]```? I understand that ```os.path.split(sys.argv[0])``` splits the directory into a head and tail, and then the ```os.path.join``` joins both of the ```sys.argv```.

Comment: The second [0] selects the first item from the (head, tail) tuple that split() returns - so its the head